# How to iterate through multiple divs of (almost) same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I got 12 divs of class `subClass`, each ending with individual number: `subClass-1` , `subClass-2` and so on. Also, for each of those classes I got same function, for example:

```
function toggleAreas1() {
      var $hide = $('.toggle-areas-1 > .row:visible');      
      $hide.fadeOut(function() {
          if ($hide.next().length) {
              $hide.next().fadeIn();
          } else {
              $hide.prevAll().last().fadeIn();
          }
      });
   }
```

But for obvious reasons, I don't want to use 12 different, yet almost identical functions, when I easily could use one, more universal.
I was thinking about something along these lines:

```
function toggleAreas1(index) {
   for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) { 
      index = i++
      var $hide = $('.toggle-areas-index > .row:visible');      
   }
      $hide.fadeOut(function() {
          if ($hide.next().length) {
              $hide.next().fadeIn();
          } else {
              $hide.prevAll().last().fadeIn();
          }
      });
   }
```

But of course it doesn't work, for my js skills are non-existent. What should I do to fix my problem?

Comment: how toggleAreas1 is called? Adding html will help to find the optimum solution

Comment: If they all do the same thing then why can't they all just be the class `.toggle-areas`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function toggleAreas1() {
  var $hide = $("[class^=toggle-areas] > .row:visible");
  $hide.fadeOut(function() {
    if ($hide.next().length) {
      $hide.next().fadeIn();
    } else {
      $hide.prevAll().last().fadeIn();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: *Note to OP:* In `[class^=toggle-areas]` the [`^=`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) is the *starts-with* selector. So it will work with `toogle-areas-1`,`toggle-areas-2`, and so on.

Comment: So, it will work even if I got, say, subClass-1 AND subClass-A?

Comment: @roonroon Is expected result to use same function for each element `.subClass-1` , `. subClass-A` separately ? Or to chain animations within a loop ?

Comment: Yes, it's kind of scoretable. 1-10 changes score and A-B changes header and description of said table.

Comment: @roonroon _"So, it will work even if I got, say, subClass-1 AND subClass-A? "_ Yes ,  `var $hide = $("[class^=toggle-areas] > .row:visible")` should select all `.row:visible` elements that are children of element where `class` begins with `"toggle-area"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use string concatenation for building jQuery selectors:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) 
{ 
    var $hide = $('.toggle-areas-' + i + ' > .row:visible'); // .toggle-areas-1, .toggle-areas-2 etc.   

    $hide.fadeOut(function() {
        if ($hide.next().length) {
            $hide.next().fadeIn();
        } else {
            $hide.prevAll().last().fadeIn();
        }
    });
}
```

However, why don't you just give them the one common class like `toggle-areas`? You can add this class **in addition** to your existent:

```
<div class="toggle-areas toggle-areas-1"></div>
<div class="toggle-areas toggle-areas-2"></div>
<div class="toggle-areas toggle-areas-3"></div>
```

Then, you will be able to do both:

```
// Affects all toogle-areas
$(".toogle-areas").fadeOut(function() {
    if ($hide.next().length) {
        $hide.next().fadeIn();
    } else {
        $hide.prevAll().last().fadeIn();
    }
});
```

and

```
// Affects only toogle-areas-2
$('.toggle-areas-2 > .row:first').show().nextAll().hide();
```

Comment: Because of `$('.toggle-areas-2 > .row:first').show().nextAll().hide();`. I need it to work for each row independently and when I set unified class name it didn't run as intented; instead it continued trouch all the rows, one after one.

Answer (score 0):

try changing 
var $hide = $('.toggle-areas-index > .row:visible'); 
to
var $hide = $('.toggle-areas-'+index+' > .row:visible');

Answer (score 0):

You would need the + operator for gluing an integer variable to strings:

i.e.

`var $hide = $('.toggle-areas-' + index + ' > .row:visible');`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are [attribute substring selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings).

So if your class begins with `subClass` use: `[class^=subClass]`

```
$('[class^=subClass]');
```

Note though that this tests against the full attribute string so if there is something else in front it will not match, ie `class="class1 subClass-1"` in which case you can use the other two `$=`, `*=` selectors. The first one doing an ends with match, the second doing a contains match.

```js
jQuery('[class^=subClass]').css({
   background:'#ffff00',  
});
```

```css
[class^=subClass] {
  width:48px;
  height:48px;
  margin-bottom:3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subClass-1"></div>
<div class="subClass-2"></div>
<div class="subClass-3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    function toggleAreas1() {
    var $hide = $('[class^=toggle-areas] > .row:visible').each(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(function() {
    // do what you need
    });
});
```